# simple sql query gone wrong

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a sql query and input that into a variable called tid. This is using the ruby on rails language where I am trying to attempt with the bottom code.

`@test = Customer.where(:email => @email).first 
tid = @test[:id]`

Moreover, it gives me a 500 Internal Error saying "Action Controller: Exception caught"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `@test` should be a Customer object or `nil`, not a Hash. You should try:

```
tid = @test.try(:id)
```

That will give you the Customer ID or `nil` in `tid`.